# How would you make discord bot send the same message over and over again (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Let's say when I typed a certain command it would repeat "Hello." and send that message a certain amount of times. How would you go about writing that.

Answer (score 0):

```py
channel = someChannel

for i in range(10):
    await channel.send("Hello")
```

will send "Hello" 10 times

Answer (score 0):

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')

@client.command()
async def repeat(ctx, msg, reps):
    for i in range(reps):
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

The user input `/repeat Hello 10`

The bot output `'Hello' 10 times`